# Spark jobs reaching "LOST" state

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I have written the below function which uses a `SparkLauncher` to submit a Spark job as a particular user. I am monitoring the jobs using `handle.getState` and they are reaching the "LOST" staus. The handle does get assigned an application ID, but calling `yarn logs -applicationId` on it reveals that no logs have been saved. Additionally, I cannot find the application ID in the history server.

```
def submitSparkJob(master: String,
                     applicationPath: String,
                     jarPaths: List[String],
                     arguments: List[String],
                     properties: Map[String, String],
                     mainClass: String): SparkAppHandle = {

    val env = Map(
      "HADOOP_USER_NAME" -> "username"
    )

    val launcher = new SparkLauncher(env.asJava)
      .setMaster(master) // "yarn" in this case
      .setDeployMode("cluster")
      .setJavaHome(configuration.underlying.getString("static.javaHome"))
      .setSparkHome(configuration.underlying.getString("static.sparkHome"))
      .setMainClass(mainClass)
      .setAppResource(applicationPath)

    for (jar <- jarPaths) {
      launcher.addJar(jar)
    }
    for (property <- properties) {
      launcher.addSparkArg(property._1, property._2)
    }
    launcher.startApplication()
  }
```

To me, it appears as if the job is never reaching yarn, despite entering "submitted" status at one point. Could something be wrong with my current configuration?

Comment: Your job could be failing before any log files are written. Say, if one of the jar-files are not present.